# Entity Framework Core Explicitly loading related data according to Type of Class

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have Repository class with includes. the code below works for one to one relationships. However for Collections I need to change `DbContext.Entry(model.Result).Reference(include).Load();` to `DbContext.Entry(model.Result).Collection(include).Load();`

```
    public virtual async Task<TEntity> GetByIdAsync(object[] keyValues,
        List<Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>> includes,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        var model = DbSet.FindAsync(keyValues, cancellationToken);
        if (includes == null) return await model;
        foreach (var include in includes)
            //if (include.Body.Type.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(ICollection<>)))
            DbContext.Entry(model.Result).Reference(include).Load();

        return await model;

        //return await DbSet.FindAsync(keyValues, cancellationToken);
    }
```

What kind of condition may I use here in order to seperate References and Collections from each other?

thank you.

Edit:
example object is

> System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[[WestCore.Domain.Entities.WestLife.MhpProduct]]

generally, the collection can be ICollection or IList.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of separate `Reference` / `Collection` methods, you can use the more general [`Navigation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.changetracking.entityentry.navigation?view=efcore-2.0#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_ChangeTracking_EntityEntry_Navigation_System_String_) method. Unfortunately it has no overload with lambda expressions, so you need to extract the property name manually. Since your method design does not support nested properties, you can get that information from lambda expression body, cast to [`MemberExpression`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.memberexpression(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
foreach (var include in includes)
{
    var propertyName = ((MemberExpression)include.Body).Member.Name;
    DbContext.Entry(model.Result).Navigation(propertyName).Load();
}
```

Comment: when I use this approach, I figured out that Entity framework is generating wrong SQL  `SELECT "e".MP_MHP_ID, "e".MP_PRODUCT_ID, "e".MP_G_ORDER, "e".G_END_DATE, "e".G_INSERT_BY, "e".G_INSERT_DATE, "e".G_IS_DELETED, "e".G_START_DATE, "e"."MP_WEST_CORE._DOMAIN._ENTITIES._WEST_LIFE._MHP_PRODUCT"
      FROM MHP_PRODUCT "e"
      WHERE "e".MP_PRODUCT_ID = :p__get_Item_0` note that I am using Devart.Oracle.DataAccess

Comment: I don't see how that can happen, since it's using the same approach used internally by `Reference` /`Collection` calls. I saw your and accepted "answers", but they use **eager loading**, while the code in questions is for  **explicit loading**. In other words, they answer different question not being asked. Of course `Include` supports expressions directly, that's pretty obvious and specified in the documentation, hence does not deserve SO Q/A.

Comment: I am still considering answers actually because it seems that @GPW 's answer also causes trouble to me. I am working on it. Your answer is pretty straight forward and I am confused about the query produced by EF. I am working on it. I will update EF Core and Devart to see what will happen

Comment: Btw, what query are you monitoring and what's wrong wit it? EF Core processes related data differently than EF6. With eager loading, it uses separate query per each collection `Include`. With explicit loading, it will execute separate query per each `Load` call. In both cases in won't be a single query.

Comment: right now the query is like this: check my answer `SELECT "product.MhpProducts".MP_MHP_ID, "product.MhpProducts".MP_PRODUCT_ID, "product.MhpProducts".MP_G_ORDER, "product.MhpProducts".G_END_DATE, "product.MhpProducts".G_INSERT_BY, "product.MhpProducts".G_INSERT_DATE, "product.MhpProducts".G_IS_DELETED, "product.MhpProducts".G_START_DATE, "product.MhpProducts"."MP_WEST_CORE._DOMAIN._ENTITIES._WEST_LIFE._MHP_PRODUCT" FROM MHP_PRODUCT "product.MhpProducts" INNER JOIN ( SELECT "product0".TP_ID FROM TREE_PRODUCT "product0" ) "t" ON "product.MhpProducts".MP_PRODUCT_ID = "t".TP_ID ORDER BY "t".TP_ID`

Comment: the problem was about HasForeignKey mapping. It is solved and your solution is properly working. Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

I'd change it so rather than expressly mimicking FindByIdAsync I'd have a slightly more flexible method:

```
public async Task<T> GetItemAsync<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter, 
          List<Expression<Func<T,object>>> includes) where T: class
{
    var model = Set<T>();
    foreach (var include in includes)
    {
        model.Include(include);
    }
    return await model.FirstOrDefaultAsync(filter);
}
```

which you'd then call with:

```
var result = GetItemAsync<MyEntity>(x => x.Id == 3, 
             new List<Expression<Func<MyEntity, object>>> 
             { 
                 x => s.SomeProperty, 
                 x => s.SomeOtherProperty
             });
```

which is very similar to yours, but a bit more flexible, and will only hit the DB once rather than lazily-loading everything separately like I believe your existing code would.  This may be your intention but we don't have that context.

Also - Calling `model.Result` and using the non-asyc `Load()` method means your code is less async-friendly than it could be...

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

I figured out that I am still having problems. Be

```
public virtual async Task<TEntity> GetByIdAsync(object[] keyValues,
        List<Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>> includes,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        Task<TEntity> model = null;

        foreach (var include in includes)
        {
            if (include.Body.Type.GetInterface(nameof(IEnumerable<TEntity>)) != null)
            { //this part generates SQL Below
                await DbSet.Include(include).LoadAsync(cancellationToken);
                model = DbSet.FindAsync(keyValues, cancellationToken);
            }
            else //this part is working
            {
                var propertyName = ((MemberExpression)include.Body).Member.Name;
                model = DbSet.FindAsync(keyValues, cancellationToken);
                await DbContext.Entry(model.Result).Navigation(propertyName).LoadAsync(cancellationToken);
            }
        }

        if (model == null)
            model = DbSet.FindAsync(keyValues, cancellationToken);

        return await model;
    }
```

IEnumerable part generates theSQL below:

> SELECT "product.MhpProducts".MP_MHP_ID, "product.MhpProducts".MP_PRODUCT_ID, "product.MhpProducts".MP_G_ORDER, "product.MhpProducts".G_END_DATE, "product.MhpProducts".G_INSERT_BY, "product.MhpProducts".G_INSERT_DATE, "product.MhpProducts".G_IS_DELETED, "product.MhpProducts".G_START_DATE, **"product.MhpProducts"."MP_WEST_CORE._DOMAIN._ENTITIES._WEST_LIFE._MHP_PRODUCT"**
>         FROM MHP_PRODUCT "product.MhpProducts"
>         INNER JOIN (
>             SELECT "product0".TP_ID
>             FROM TREE_PRODUCT "product0"
>         ) "t" ON "product.MhpProducts".MP_PRODUCT_ID = "t".TP_ID
>         ORDER BY "t".TP_ID